# Toggle Image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

Here's the simpler code. Sorry, I'm new here.

If the loginbutton is clicked. It will show down the login container. Please help. Thanks.

```
 <html>
 <head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login").click(function(){
$("#login_container").slideToggle("500");
});
});
</script>
<style>
#login {
background-image:url(images/loginbutton.jpg);
width:65px;
height:22px;
float:left;
 }
 #login_container {
background-image:url(images/logincontainer.jpg);


 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="login">
 <div id="login_container">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. And you might want to look into using .on() in lieu .click().

Comment: Please post your HTML. Also, it's a good idea to try to recreate the issue using JSFiddle.com. It will give us a working sample to look at, and there's also a good chance you'll discover the problem for yourself without having to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. Are you sure you have added the jQuery file in your code?

Plus I would recommend you to add "display: none" to .login_container. Or use hide(), like this:

```
$('.login_container').hide();

$('.login').click(function() {
    $('.login_container').slideToggle(500);
});
```